# How can i convert an array

Tags: arrays, formatting

im working with a fax service and i like to merge a fax with multiple html urls sources over a form.

the script works with the following array:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" [1]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" }
```

my array looks like this

```
array(2) { ["files"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" [1]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" } ["send"]=> string(4) "Send" }
```

i have no idea how can i change the array in the correct format. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This question doesn't have any language tags. Was this written in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
$a = array(2) { ["files"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" [1]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" } ["send"]=> string(4) "Send" }
```

then

```
$b=$a['files']
```

and $b will be

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" [1]=> string(32) "https://www.test.net/test.pdf" }
```

conversely

```
$c=[];
$c['files']=$b;
$c['send']="Send";
```

and $c will be the same as $a